# Why does an F# Discriminated Union fails to have its TypeConverter respected by JSON.NET but other types can?

Tags: f#, json.net, typeconverter, discriminated-union, jsonconvert

```
#r "../packages/Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3/lib/netstandard2.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
type [<Struct; System.ComponentModel.TypeConverterAttribute(typeof<CC>)>] C = A of string
and CC() = 
    inherit System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter()
    override _.CanConvertFrom (_, t) = t = typeof<string>
    override _.ConvertFrom(_, _, s) = s :?> string |> A |> box<C>
    override _.CanConvertTo (_, t) = t = typeof<string>
    override _.ConvertTo(_, _, s, _) = s :?> C |> fun (A s) -> s |> box<string>
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject {|a = A "123"|}
```

This results in `val it : string = "{"a":{"Case":"A","Fields":["123"]}}"`, which indicates that the `TypeConverter` is not respected. This also happens for reference DUs.

However, this does not happen with `JsonConverter`s:

```
#r "../packages/Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3/lib/netstandard2.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
type [<Struct; Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof<CC>)>] C = A of string
and CC() = 
    inherit Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter()
    override _.CanConvert t = t = typeof<string>
    override _.ReadJson (r, _, _, _) = r.ReadAsString() |> A |> box<C>
    override _.WriteJson (w, v, _) = v :?> C |> fun (A s) -> s |> w.WriteValue
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject {|a = A "123"|}
```

This results in `val it : string = "{"a":"123"}"`.

Compare this with records:

```
#r "../packages/Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3/lib/netstandard2.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
type [<Struct; System.ComponentModel.TypeConverterAttribute(typeof<CC>)>] C = { A: string }
and CC() = 
    inherit System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter()
    override _.CanConvertFrom (_, t) = t = typeof<string>
    override _.ConvertFrom(_, _, s) = { A = s :?> string } |> box<C>
    override _.CanConvertTo (_, t) = t = typeof<string>
    override _.ConvertTo(_, _, s, _) = (s :?> C).A |> box<string>
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject {|a = { A = "123"}|}
```

This also results in `val it : string = "{"a":"123"}"`, which indicates that the `TypeConverter` is respected.

This shows that something is preventing `TypeConverter`s in discriminated unions from being recognized. What would be the reason? `JsonConverter`s are not usable in dictionary keys, so I would expect `TypeConverter`s to perform better. What would be a viable approach to correctly serialize the aforementioned discriminated union?

Comment: I think I know what your problem is, but I can't get your code to compile.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/hWmNcz.  Can you please [edit] your question to fix compilation?  Does the following correctly fix the compilation?  https://dotnetfiddle.net/lQ4Ouf.  A [mcve] would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that Json.NET has its own built-in converter for discriminated unions, [`DiscriminatedUnionConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/DiscriminatedUnionConverter.cs).  Any applicable `JsonConverter` will always supersede an applied `TypeConverter`.

A built-in converter can be disabled by providing your own, alternate, `JsonConverter`, either in [settings](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) or via an applied [`JsonConverterAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm).  You have already created a converter that correctly converts your type `C`, but if you would prefer to fall back to the applied `TypeConverter`, you can create a `JsonConverter` that does nothing and falls back on default serialization by returning `false` from [`CanRead`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanRead.htm) and [`CanWrite`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanWrite.htm):

```
type NoConverter<'a> () =
    inherit JsonConverter()
    override this.CanConvert(t) = (t = typedefof<'a>)
    override this.CanRead = false
    override this.CanWrite = false
    override this.WriteJson(_, _, _) =  raise (NotImplementedException());
    override this.ReadJson(_, _, _, _) =  raise (NotImplementedException());
```

Then apply it to your type as follows (demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jsoKV4)):

```
type [<JsonConverterAttribute(typeof<NoConverter<C>>); System.ComponentModel.TypeConverterAttribute(typeof<CC>)>] C = A of string
and CC() = 
    inherit System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter()
    override this.CanConvertFrom (_, t) = (t = typeof<string>)
    override this.ConvertFrom(_, _, s) = s :?> string |> A |> box<C>
    override this.CanConvertTo (_, t) = t = typeof<string>
    override this.ConvertTo(_, _, s, _) = s :?> C |> fun (A s) -> s |> box<string>

printfn "%s" (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(A "123"))
```

Or, use it in settings as follows (demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F4jjx9)):

```
let settings = JsonSerializerSettings(Converters = [|NoConverter<C>()|])
printfn "%s" (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(A "123", settings))
```